# Does "S3 Compatible Storage" support event / webhooks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud-storage

Just trying to understand if S3 compatible storage supports events as in AWS S3 as in [Amazon S3 Event Notifications - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html)?

If yes, how do I access them?

My organisation is using on premise S3-compatible storage. I would like a webhook to be called for post-processing when a file is uploaded to a certain bucket.

Comment: Which S3 compatible storage are you using? Generic answer: it depends.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in practice it would probably depend on what your vendor provides.  E.g. [MinIO](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-bucket-notification-guide.html) mostly supports it (but see the exception on that page).  The actual streaming solutions to which it can send the notifications will probably be different from what AWS offers.

Other "S3 compatible" object stores may have differing interpretations of how to run events.